# Update postgresql table with data from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, psycopg2

I have a table with my basedata as a postgresql table, let this be 'basedata':

```
basedata:

id,name,age,height
1,john,17,185
2,nick,24,174
3,sarah,19,165
```

This a postgresql table with the primary key 'id'.

Now i will receive a pandas dataframe with new data or updated data on the respective person, for example:

```
new_data:

id,name,age,height
17,harry,26,177
23,mary,14,145
2,nick,25,174
3,sarah,19,165
```

The logic schould be:

```
new id -> insert into database
id already exists -> do nothing if every field is the same (like for sarah)
id already exists -> update differing fields
```

Result shoud be:

```
basedata:

id,name,age,height
1,john,17,185
2,nick,25,174
3,sarah,19,165
17,harry,26,177
23,mary,14,145
```

I am struggling how to do this with `python` and `psycopg2` in the best way.

I need to iterate over the DataFrame and check every datarow against the Database, or is there any more elegant way how to do this? And how to iterate the best way through the dataframe?

Comment: You say you're struggling, but what have you actually tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: do you want use pandas? In pandas this is simple

Comment: @HampusLarsson "And how to iterate the best way through the dataframe?" I want to iterate in a way, that i can easily compare the current datarow against the db.

Comment: @ansev to use pandas would be nice, yes. but as i saig, i am struggling with the right way of iteration, so that i can compare easily against the data in the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in SQL level instead of iterating over the DataFrame. (Can't provide an exact solution from code level since you haven't provided code snippet)

- Assuming table creation would be like below,

```
CREATE TABLE basedata (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
   name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   age INTEGER NOT NULL,
   height INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

**New Data**

```
INSERT INTO basedata (id,name, age, height)
VALUES
   (1, 'john', 17, 185),
   (2, 'nick', 24, 174),
   (3, 'sarah', 19, 165);
```

**Update Data**

```
INSERT INTO basedata (id, name, age, height)
VALUES
   (17, 'harry', 26, 177),
   (23, 'mary', 14, 145),
   (2, 'nick', 25, 174),
   (3, 'sarah', 19, 165)
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO NOTHING;
```

For more clarification:-  [PostgreSQL Upsert Using INSERT ON CONFLICT statement](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/)

Answer (score -1):

Using `sqlalchemy`, and assuming a dataframe `new_data`, the flow would be as follow:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(my_postgresql_db_uri)
con = engine.connect()

table_name = 'basedata'

base_data = pd.read_sql(table_name, con)

data = pd.append(base_data, new_data, ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()

data.to_sql(table_name, con, if_exists='replace')
```

This is untested and not really optimized, as you would have to read the table everytime you want to update your table, [because](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14553) you can't have 'INSERT OR UPDATE' in pandas.to_sql